# Deriving a unique and ordered list from a complex dictionary

Tags: python, list, unique

I have a nested list of tuples, that I need to break out into a single list and drop the first  ordinal of each. I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this.

I have sample data such as:

```
[[('Item 1', <__main__.J object at 0x1018fc690>), ('Item 2', <__main__.J object at 0x1018fc6d0>)]]
```

and I am trying to reduce that to

```
[<__main__.J object at 0x1018fc690>, <__main__.J object at 0x1018fc6d0>]
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction. I've tried itertools and zip(*) to no avail.

```
import itertools
import operator

class J(object):
    pass

w = J()
w.Type = 'Item 1'
w.Page = 35
w.Fragment = 'AA'

q = J()
q.Type = 'Item 2'
q.Page = 78
q.Fragment = 'BA'

z = [[('Item 1', w),('Item 2', q)]]
y = [b for b in z]
print y

result = ([ a for a,b in z ], [ b for a,b in z ])
print result
print zip(*z)
```

Comment: Is your input list always a list of lists of tuples, or is it arbitrarily nested? The answers so far are on the right track but it gets a bit more complicated if the nesting could be arbitrarily deep.

Comment: Yeah, the nesting is the issue that is hurting me. The solution by Christian works for my test case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you are looking for?

```
result = [c[1] for b in z for c in b]
print result
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
>>> lis = [[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]]
```

`zip`:

```
>>> zip(*lis[0])[1]
('a', 'b')
```

List Comprehension:

```
>>> [y for _, y in lis[0]]
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, but that doesn't seem to work. using the sample that I provided. print zip(*z)[1] yields [('Item 2', <__main__.J object at 0x1018f36d0>)]

Comment: OP has another list inside the first one. :P

Comment: @Baywatch Ah! I missed that you've a nested list, try: `zip(*lis[0])[1]
`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @Christian's answer (and there's nothing wrong with that answer), you can also do this using `itertools` to flatten the list:

```
result = [c[1] for c in itertools.chain.from_iterable(z)]
```

I'd go with whichever construction you find easier to follow. Both assume only one level of nesting - dealing with arbitrarily deep nesting could be done with a recursive handler.

Comment: recursive handlers sound fun. I must check up on those.

Comment: If you get into that design, this answer looks like a decent start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python - except that you'd have to tweak it a bit because your lowest level elements are tuples, which are iterable.